# Can I subclass dict in python and avoid copying it's data?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, initialization

Consider I have the following code:

```
class MyDict(dict):
  def __init__(self, original_dict):
    dict.__init__(self, original_dict) # THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM
    self.bar = 'baz'

  def foo(self): return self.bar
```

This may seem pretty innocent, but in my application the dict copying that happens when calling the superclass `__init__` is a serious performance problem since that takes O(`len(original_dict)`) time and I am doing this many times for relatively long dicts. I believe it should be possible to do this in O(1) time if I could somehow replace `self` with `original_dict` instead and then do the rest of the initialization.

Normally I think this could be possible to circumvent by not subclassing dict and using regular functions instead. But this is not possible since `MyDict` is a library class that I actually want to use and perhaps subclass to solve this problem. I was thinking about perhaps overriding `__new__` but I neither sure how to exactly do that to achieve the desired effect nor am I sure if that would justified in this case since it's generally considered a bad practice for a good reason.

Comment: What should happen if a change is made in `original_dict`?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem exactly you are talking about. Creating a regular dictionary in Python with `dict(other_dict)` will create a copy of `other_dict`. Creating an instance of `MyDict` with `MyDict(other_dict)` also copies `other_dict` once, so apart from some function call overhead, there doesn't seem to be a difference in performance.

Comment: @DaniMesejo If the `MyDict` instance is changed as well then that's okay.  But I think I could guarantee it's actually never changed after it's used to construct `MyDict` instance / subclass instance.

Comment: @SvenMarnach the making of the copy is the problem. I don't want it copied, I want it reused directly. The copying process is surprisingly a big overhead in my application as shown by profiler, the code spends most time doing `MyDict.__init__` over and over.

Comment: What about just pointing it to the same value instead of copying? Also what is the purpose of subclassing dict?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do if I were to implement the class. To be honest, I am not sure what is the intended purpose of subclassing dict here. I am the library user, not developer.

Comment: So your problem is that the library you are using is copying a dictionary that you don't want to be copied. I guess then your options are to either not use that library, or change it to not copy the dict? I'm still confused by this question, and the problem seems to have nothing at all to do with subclassing `dict`.

Comment: Maybe I get it now. You want to turn a dictionary of built-in type `dict` into the class `MyDict` from a third-party library without copying the contents of your existing dictionary. This is impossible, since these two classes – `dict` and `MyDict` – have different memory representations. This is unrelated to the line you highlighted, though – even a trivial subclass like `class A(dict): pass` would still have the same problem.

Comment: What you possibly _can_ do is creating your other dictionary as a `MyDict` in the first place, rather than creating it as a `dict` first.

Comment: That could be possible. I'll see how it works in reality.